# How to toggle an error modal after we reject a promise in a JavaScript promise chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am creating an input form where users can enter hours for each day they worked. I want to show an error modal if the number of hours entered on an input form is greater than the limit. After the "Save" button is clicked, I need to check the time limits, save the user data to the DB, and refresh the table.

I am trying to use JavaScript promise chains to make sure that we wait for the result of one step to return a result before executing the next asynchronous step. I catch any errors thrown after we reject a promise at the end of the promise chain to toggle the modal.

```
$('#saveForm').on('click', function (e) {
    
    checkDailyTimeLimit()
        .then(data => checkWeeklyTimeLimit())
        .then(data => saveData())
        .then(data => getData())
        .then(data => populateDataInTable())
        .catch(error => {
             $('#modal').modal('toggle')
             $('#modalBody').html(error)
        })
}

function checkDailyTimeLimit() {
    return currTime > timeLimit 
        ? reject('Time limit exceeded. Please enter time that is below 24 hours')
        : resolve(true)
}
```

The promise is rejected if the time entered is over the limit, but when the catch block is executed, the modal does not show up and the error is undefined. However, if I add error callbacks in the `.then()` argument and toggle the modal there, it works and the toggle function in the catch block is not executed.

This code is with the error callbacks defined after each promise.

```
checkDailyTimeLimit()
    .then(data => checkWeeklyTimeLimit(), error => toggleModal(error))
    .then(data => saveData(), error => toggleModal(error))

function toggleModal(error) {
    $('#modal').modal('toggle')
    $('#modalBody').html(error)
}
```

Why does it toggle the modal in the immediate error callbacks of the promise and not in the catch block at the end of the promise chain?

How would I simplify this code to only have one error callback or catch block that takes in errors from different promises and toggles the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds complicated. By setting the attributes `required`, `min="0"` and `max="24"` on the input element the form will only submit if the user enter a number between 0 and 24. That could be a start, and then you can do the AJAX request on the submit event.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Form is submitting...');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.validity.rangeOverflow) {
    e.target.closest('label').classList.add('invalid');
  }
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.closest('label').classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
```

```css
label~div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.invalid~div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Enter time:<input type="number" name="time" min="0" max="24" required/></label>
  <div>Time limit exceeded. Please enter time that is below 24 hours.</div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```